# Variable lengths differ

Tags: r

I try to run the following code

```
set.seed(123)

training.sample <- DSM_data$OC %>%
    createdataPartition(p=0.8, list=FALSE)

train.data <- DSM_data[training.sample]
MLR.rh <- lm(OC ~ DSM_data[,6] + DSM_data[,7] + DSM_data[,13], data=train.data)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting an error of variable lengths differ, kindly help me solve this.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = OC ~ DSM_data[, 6] + DSM_data[,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'DSM_data[, 6]')
```

Comment: You need to add some representative data to make your example [reproducible](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html). But generally the problem is coming from subsetting in the formula; if you're using the `data` param of a model, the formula should [mostly] only be composed of unquoted column names.

Answer (score 1):

Create something like your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
set.seed(123)

DSM_data = data.frame(OC=rnorm(100),matrix(rnorm(1300),ncol=13))

training.sample <- DSM_data$OC %>%
    createDataPartition(p=0.8, list=FALSE)
```

Your error comes here:

```
 train.data <- DSM_data[training.sample]
 dim(train.data)
 NULL
```

It's only taking out the first column. It should be (note the , between square brackets) :

```
train.data <- DSM_data[training.sample,]
```

Then inside the linear model, use the variable names:

```
colnames(train.data)
[1] "OC"  "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10" "X11"
[13] "X12" "X13"

MLR.rh <- lm(OC ~ X1 + X2 + X5, data=train.data)
```

Or you can subset the columns based on the variables you need(include the dependent), and use the tilda `~` to specify all other variables besides `OC` :

```
MLR.rh <- lm(OC ~ ., data=train.data[,c(1,6,7,13)])
```